# Passport local mongoose cb is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js

im getting a problem while trying to register with passport local mongoose.

When i submit the registration form this error logs:

[image]

User:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    email: String
});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

User Controller:

```
var db                    = require('../vendor/db'),
    passport              = require('passport'),
    User                  = require('../model/user');


module.exports = {
    register: function(req, res){
        User.register(new User({email: req.body.email, username: req.body.username}, req.body.password, function (err, user) {
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                return res.render('user/register.twig');
            }
            passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
               res.redirect("/home");
            });
        }));
    },
    isLoggedIn: function (req, res, next) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated())
            return next();
        res.redirect('/');
    }
};
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, I was missing a ")" in new User()

It should be like this:

```
new User({email: req.body.email, username: req.body.username}),req.body.password, function (err, user) {...
```